# Solving PDE with non constant coefficients when the unknown function depends on more than one variable

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Need to solve this PDE for my research work. Tried substitution $y=x^m$ and also power series method but could not get the solution to $a_3$.
Equation: $$\left[-\frac{2m}{r}-2\left(1-\frac{2m}r\right)^{-1}\cdot \frac{m}{r^2}\right]a_3 + m\frac{\partial a_3}{\partial r}=0.$$
where $a_3$ depends on $4$ functions $t,r, \theta,\phi$.
If anybody can help!

Comment: What you have given is not an equation.

Comment: If the expression above is equal to zero then it is a separable ODE where the 'constant' of integration is functionally dependent on $t, \theta, \phi$.

Comment: @Masterpiece How familiar are you with ODEs? You should be able to solve separable ODEs before you try to learn anything about PDEs. For instance, could you solve $\frac{dx}{dt} = xt$? The method will end up being much the same.

Answer (score 0):

According to wolfram alpha for example (if I typed it right)
$$
a_3(t,r,\phi,\theta)=g(t,\phi,\theta)(r-2m)^{1/m}r^{2-\frac1m}.
$$
An equation with only one partial derivative means that you treat the other variables as constants. A PDE means several different partial derivatives at the same time: then things become more involved.